# Dataset and its Quantitave Representation

Tags: probability, statistics, data-analysis, descriptive-statistics

I've been given the question:
$$\mbox{Given the dataset, with 15 observations}$$
$$\left(4,55;\; 6,51;\; 3,04; \; 5,60;\; 3,69;\; 5,12;\; 7,31;\; 7,80;\; 8,31;\; 3,83;\; 4,44;\; 6,47;\; 6,14;\; 8;76;\; 7,67 \right)$$
$\textbf{a)}$ Calculate the mean, standard deviation, coefficient of variation and quartiles. Build a $box-plot$.

$\textbf{b)}$ Interpret the results.

There is nothing in my notes showing the use of the semicolon ';' in the description of a dataset. I interpret this as such:
$$\mbox{There are 4 occurences of 55 in class 1}$$
$$\mbox{There are 6 occurences of 51 in class 2}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\mbox{There are 7 occurences of 67 in class 15}$$
Them with this interpretation, we have

$\textbf{a)}$ The median is
$$\overline{x} = \sum \frac{4(55) + 6(51) + \cdots + 7(67)}{4+6+ \cdots + 7} \approx 48,756$$
The standard deviation will be
$$s^2 = \frac{\sum (x_i - \overline{x})^2}{82} = \frac{(55 - 48,756)^2 + (51 - 48,756)^2 + \cdots + (67 - 48,756)^2}{82} \approx 110,031$$
The coefficient of variation will be
$$CV(X) = \frac{s}{\overline{x}} = \frac{\sqrt{s^2}}{\bar{x}} \approx \frac{10,49}{48,756} \approx 0,215$$
The $box-plot$ can be drawn using
$$Q_1 = \frac{n+1}{4} = \frac{82+1}{4} = 20,75$$
$$Q_2 = \frac{n+1}{2} = 41,5$$
$$Q_3 = \frac{3(n+1)}{4} = 62,25$$

$\textbf{b)}$ The results can be interpreted from $\overline{x}$, $s$ and the $box-plot$.

Is this interpretation of the semicolon in given the dataset correct?

Comment: No, it says 15 observations so your interpretation is not right. I'd assume the commas are decimal points - that's standard in many countries.

Comment: Maybe, commas are common here for decimals. But it really depends on the teacher, that's why I'm unsure.

Comment: @Nikolawn Usually it depends on the country and context what , and ; mean. In Germany we use this notation to list floating point numbers. Anglo-american notation would start with $4.55, 6.51, ...$

Comment: I see. Most likelly ';' separetes each observation and ',' just denotes decimals just like @M T said. Thanks!